# How to capture SMB/CIFS packets in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, packet-sniffers, smb, cifs

```
Socket socket1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

socket1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 0));

socket1.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);

byte[] byTrue = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
byte[] byOut = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };

socket1.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut);

byte[] buffer1 = new byte[4096];

socket1.BeginReceive(buffer1, 0, buffer1.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), new Tuple<Socket, byte[]>(socket1, buffer1));
```

I use this code to capture IP packets, on an adapter over all ports.

How would I modify this code to capture SMB/CIFS packets?  It is not preferred to add an additional packet capture library to the project/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code DOES capture SMB packets.